# Unintended replication of behavior of other object

Tags: java, swing, object, attributes

I have a little fun personal project where I move a "robot" in a box arena, if he hits a wall, the game is over. It has an automated walking mode to where he moves around the arena without hitting walls using an finite state machine. The arena is printed using Strings and Java Swing UI, and everything controlled by swing events.

I'm trying to make him shoot. Since the bullet behavior is pretty similar to the robot behavior, I created an Super Class named entity with all similar methods and attributes (like position coordinates and direction), and then extended the robot and bullet class.

The problem is: when I move (change the position attribute of robot) bullet position is changed too. 
My UI shows the current position of both objects and when I move the robot, the bullet moves. The bullet position was only intended to be set when I pressed the shoot button. The shoot button sets the bullet position to the robot and then move the bullet in the same direction until it hits the box limits.

What is happening when I shoot is the same of robot movement: when the bullet move, the robot moves to, suiciding in the wall with the bullet.

It's like they are the same object, but I'm pretty sure I'm calling the move method using the right object.

As asked, I made a MCVE version below:

Entity Super Class

```
public abstract class Entity {
    protected int[] position = new int[2];
    protected char direction;

    public int getPosI() {
        // System.out.println("i: " + position[0]);
        return position[0];
    }

    public int getPosJ() {
        // System.out.println("j: " + position[1]);
        return position[1];
    }

    public int[] getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int[] position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public char getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(char direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public boolean move() {

        switch (direction) {
        case 'u':
            if (this.position[0] != 0) {
                this.position[0]--;
                return true;
            } else
                return false;

        case 'r':
            if (this.position[1] != 3) {
                this.position[1]++;
                return true;
            } else
                return false;

        case 'd':
            if (this.position[0] != 3) {
                this.position[0]++;
                return true;
            } else
                return false;

        case 'l':
            if (this.position[1] != 0) {
                this.position[1]--;
                return true;
            } else
                return false;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Robot Class

```
public class Robot extends Entity {


    public Robot(int[] position) {
        super();
        this.position = position;
        this.direction = 'u';

    }

    public void resetPos() {
        this.position[0] = this.position[1] = 1;
    }

}
```

Bullet class

```
public class Bala extends Entity{


    public Bala(int[] position, char direction) {
        this.position = position;
        this.direction = direction;
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
public class Main {
    private static final int[] start = new int[] { 1, 1 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot robot = new Robot(start);
        robot.setDirection('d');
        Bala bala = new Bala(robot.getPosition(), robot.getDirection());

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("MOVING ONLY THE ROBOT...");
            robot.move();

            System.out.println("Robot position: "
                    + String.valueOf(robot.getPosI()) + ", "
                    + String.valueOf(robot.getPosJ()));
            System.out.println("Bullet position: "
                    + String.valueOf(bala.getPosI()) + ", "
                    + String.valueOf(bala.getPosJ()));


        }

        System.out.println("but the bullet moves to!!!");

        System.out.println("reseting position of robot and lets see what happens to bullet...");

        robot.resetPos();

        System.out.println("Robot position: "
                + String.valueOf(robot.getPosI()) + ", "
                + String.valueOf(robot.getPosJ()));
        System.out.println("Bullet position: "
                + String.valueOf(bala.getPosI()) + ", "
                + String.valueOf(bala.getPosJ()));

        System.out.println("bullet moves too...");
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT THING: When I move the robot using the R (reset) button it moves the bullet too. Which means the bullet is moving even if a don't use the move method!!!**

So, as a direct question as requested, 
"The robot object is replicating changes in his position attribute to the bullet position and vice versa, how to stop this behavior?"

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: BTW - Wow!  4 uncompilable code snippets, 3 **!!!** and a slew of words and not one single '?'.  Do you *have* a question?

Comment: I think its pretty clear what the problem is: the bullet is moving when the robot is moving and vice versa, wich causes the shoot command to move the robot with the bullet, not only the bullet. The shoot command is the space event.

Comment: Knowing the problem is different from solving it.

Comment: OK. Let me put that another way.  It's clear to you, but is it clear to anyone else?  Adding an MCVE & an explicit question will help make it clear to others.  As it is, I voted to close for lack of an MCVE.

Comment: OK i didnt know about this MVCE need, since my previous questions here where pretty simple and didnt need it. Added a question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62078/discussion-between-diedre-and-andrew-thompson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Robot and Bala share **the exact same int array**, and therein lies your problem, with the guilty code being here:

```
Bala bala = new Bala(robot.getPosition(), robot.getDirection());
```

One possible solution, have `getPosition()` return a copy of the array, or another is to create a new array in the constructor that copies the values in the parameter.

---

As an aside, your posted code was pretty close to being an MCVE standard and only required a few changes to make it closer still. For what it's worth, this is how I changed your code to make it an MCVE and to fix it:

```
public class Main {
   private static final int[] start = new int[] { 1, 1 };

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Robot robot = new Robot(start);
      robot.setDirection('d');
      Bala bala = new Bala(robot.getPosition(), robot.getDirection());

      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         System.out.println("MOVING ONLY THE ROBOT...");
         robot.move();

         System.out.println("Robot position: "
               + String.valueOf(robot.getPosI()) + ", "
               + String.valueOf(robot.getPosJ()));
         System.out.println("Bullet position: "
               + String.valueOf(bala.getPosI()) + ", "
               + String.valueOf(bala.getPosJ()));

      }

      System.out.println("but the bullet moves to!!!");

      System.out.println("reseting position of robot and lets see what happens to bullet...");

      robot.resetPos();

      System.out.println("Robot position: " + String.valueOf(robot.getPosI())
            + ", " + String.valueOf(robot.getPosJ()));
      System.out.println("Bullet position: " + String.valueOf(bala.getPosI())
            + ", " + String.valueOf(bala.getPosJ()));

      System.out.println("bullet moves too...");
   }
}

abstract class Entity {
   protected int[] position = new int[2];
   protected char direction;

   public Entity(int[] position) {
      System.arraycopy(position, 0, this.position, 0, position.length);
   }

   public Entity(int[] position, char direction) {
      this(position);
      this.direction = direction;
   }

   public int getPosI() {
      // System.out.println("i: " + position[0]);
      return position[0];
   }

   public int getPosJ() {
      // System.out.println("j: " + position[1]);
      return position[1];
   }

   public int[] getPosition() {
      return position;
   }

   public void setPosition(int[] position) {
      this.position = position;
   }

   public char getDirection() {
      return direction;
   }

   public void setDirection(char direction) {
      this.direction = direction;
   }

   public boolean move() {

      switch (direction) {
      case 'u':
         if (this.position[0] != 0) {
            this.position[0]--;
            return true;
         } else
            return false;

      case 'r':
         if (this.position[1] != 3) {
            this.position[1]++;
            return true;
         } else
            return false;

      case 'd':
         if (this.position[0] != 3) {
            this.position[0]++;
            return true;
         } else
            return false;

      case 'l':
         if (this.position[1] != 0) {
            this.position[1]--;
            return true;
         } else
            return false;

      default:
         return false;
      }
   }
}

class Robot extends Entity {

   public Robot(int[] position) {
      super(position, 'u');

   }

   public void resetPos() {
      this.position[0] = this.position[1] = 1;
   }

}

class Bala extends Entity {

   public Bala(int[] position, char direction) {
      super(position, direction);
   }
}
```

---

As an aside, you will probably not want to use chars to represent direction but rather a Direction enum since this will add compile-time type safety to your program.

Comment: I used the copy() method for this, is it the best way? Also, i didnt understand why that happened, each object should have its own attributes, if not it destroys the holy purpose of the Super Class... This only happens with arrays?

Comment: @Diedre: No, there's nothing magical about arrays, but it happens because you are passing a **reference** type as a parameter, and you will want to study up on what that means. While each object will have its own array variable, both of those variables will be referencing the same array object. This concept is **very** important and underlies much of Java programming.

Comment: So its like pointers in C, i tought java didnt have this. Thanks

Comment: @Diedre: it does not have direct pointers, but it has them indirectly as reference variables.